# Getting an error when calculating Z score

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the outliers in my dataset and remove them. So I did the following:

```
z_scores = stats.zscore(dataset_sex)
abs_z_scores = np.abs(z_scores)
filtered_entries = (abs_z_scores < 3).all(axis=1)
new_df = dataset_sex[filtered_entries]
new_df.head()
```

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

The error seems to generate from the first line of code (z_scores = stats.zscore(dataset_sex)). I don't understand why. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from some of your data in the columns being strings (in python terms `'str'`).
When it comes from working out the z-score, it will have to divide the mean with a standard deviation.  One of the columns is a string like 'M' or 'F' for sex, or strings like '1,232.23' not converted to floats, and z-scoring does not work for that.

My first suggestion is to check that they are all numbers.

```
df.dtypes
```

will show you what types they are and then convert them to numeric.

Post a little of the data (a couple of rows) and we can help you.